# How to validate fields if bloc provider, event, state is already implemented

Tags: flutter, validation, events, state, bloc

In flutter bloc provider is already implemented with events and state to perform the api calls and loading data in the widget. Now I want to do validate fields and then perform the API calls.

I couldn't find a proper explanation for my scenario. Could flutter experts can share thier knowledge it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: too vague, please update the post with what you have tried and what exactly you want to achieve.